# How to print colorbar data from pick_event

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, figure, colorbar

```
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            sub_image = self.image[i*8:i*8+8, j*8:j*8+8]                           
            ax = plt.subplot(gs[4 - i, j], picker = True, label = self.iD)         
            c = ax.pcolormesh(sub_image, vmin=0, vmax=maxZ, cmap="viridis")    
            ax.axis("off")
            ax.set_aspect("equal")

            self.grid[4-i,j] = self.iD
            self.iD += 1
           
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.71, left=.285, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)
    self.cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])
    self.cbar = fig.colorbar(c, cax=self.cbar_ax)
    self.cbar.set_label("Charge (Photoelectrons)", rotation=270, size=24, labelpad=24)
    self.cbar_ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)
    fig.suptitle(f"Run {self.run} Event {self.ev}", fontsize=30)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event",self.nextWindow)
    
    self.layout.addWidget(self.static_canvas,1,1)#,1,2)
    self.toolBar = NavigationToolbar(self.static_canvas, self)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.toolBar,2,1,1,2)
```

[snapshot of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vbTZ.png)
I am trying to create the functionality for when a pick_event is processed, the value that corresponds with the colorbar is printed. When the cursor is over any part of the plot, the NavigationToolbar2QT displays the value I want on the bottom right, but I dont know how to access it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to access the data. I then formatted the string to get the data I want.

```
data = self.toolBar._mouse_event_to_message(event.mouseevent)
```